# Replace description of abbreviation in list of acronyms

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

For my current protocol I use the Glossaries package and everthing works fine. But I want some things to **modify** and for this I need some hints.
I use an abbreviation that is in english. So in the list of acronyms I would like to give more details as only the long form of the acronym.

**Example:**

- **acronym**: *AC*
- **description**:  *alternating current [engl.: „Wechselstrom“; meint auch Gleichspannung]*
  In the text obviously I just want to display *Wechselstrom* as long form.

So what do I to adjust? Thanks!

little example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[acronyms,nomain]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ac}{AC}{Wechselstrom}

\begin{document}
\printacronyms

Some text about \gls{ac}. Some further text about \gls{ac} to show the abbreviation displayed.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to insert the description-option like

```
[description={ alternating current [engl.: \glqq Wechselstrom\grqq; meint auch Gleichspannung]}]
```